# How to unit test through the API in this case?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class FTPOperation that I use as a base class to regroup methods that are common to FTP operations. One of these methods is connect().

```
public abstract class FtpOperation {

    protected static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(FtpOperation.class);

    /**
     * Hostname or IP address of the FTP server (e.g. localhost, 127.0.0.1).
     */
    private String hostName;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    protected FTPClient ftpClient = getFTPClient();

    public void setHostName(String hostName) {
        this.hostName = hostName;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * Connect to the specified FTP server.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected void connect() throws Exception {
        int reply;

        // Connect to the FTP server
        ftpClient.connect(hostName);
        if (!ftpClient.login(username, password))
            throw new Exception("Fail to log in with the given credentials.");

        log.info("Connected to " + hostName + ".");
        log.info(ftpClient.getReplyString());

        // Check if the connection succeeded
        reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
            throw new Exception("Connection to FTP server failed with code "
                    + reply + ".");
    }

        /**
     * Used for mocking.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    protected FTPClient getFTPClient() {
        if (this.ftpClient == null)
            this.ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        return ftpClient;
    }
}
```

I want to write unit test for testing this method but I don't know how to test it. I use Mockito to create a mock object for the FTPClient instance.
First, I thought about testing the different cases where the ftpClient.connect() call returns a certain exception, but I think it's wrong since I'm testing by knowing the implementation of the connect() method and not trough the API.
On example of test I've done:

```
@Test(expected = SocketException.class)
public void testConnectSocketException() throws Exception {
    downloadInitialFileTasklet.setHostName("hostname");
    doThrow(new SocketException()).when(mockFtpClient).connect("hostname");

    downloadInitialFileTasklet.connect();
}
```

Could someone explain me the right way to test this method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your test meant to be testing? If you're simply seeing that SocketException is not caught it seems a bit of a peculiar test.

If you were to wrap the exception then it makes a little bit more sense.
eg.

```
protected void connect() throws FTPException {
    int reply;

    // Connect to the FTP server
    try {
        ftpClient.connect(hostName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new FTPException(e, "unable to connect to: "+hostname);
    }
    ...
}
```

With the test we're testing that connect correctly terminates early and throws an FTPException if the underlying client cannot connect

```
@Test(expected = FTPException.class)
public void ConnectFailsIfExceptionOnClientConnect() throws FTPException {
    // setup
    downloadInitialFileTasklet.setHostName("hostname");
    when(mockFtpClient).connect(any(String.class)).doThrow(new SocketException());

    // verify -- if something else throws an FTP exception later then the verify
    // statements should fail the test because either connect was not called 
    // because or login was
    verify(mockFtpClient).connect(any(String.class));
    verify(mockFtpClient, never()).login(any(String.class), any(String.class));

    downloadInitialFileTasklet.connect();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface for the FtpClient class, than wrap it into a new class that you will use in the production environment.

For tests instead you can implement a stub (a fake class) or a mock object of the wrapped FtpClient (I prefer the first way).

Pass the IFtpClient interface to the constructor of the FtpOperation class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I've an example of hardware testing but it's in C#. Do you want it?